# how to change button cursor to pointer if button not disabled in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

I want this button when not disabled to have a cursor pointer (hand) instead of default (arrow).

The button disabled property is managed by a variable in Angular component

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="user==undefined">Login</button>
```

Comment: bootstrap button default get the cursor point but in case any issue you can apply this css -- cursor: pointer; to get it.

Comment: @SumitPatel True

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS rule :

```
button:not(disabled){
    cursor: pointer
}
```